# Convert nginx config to apache24

Tags: apache, nginx

I need to convert this snippet of code, from a Nginx config file to Apache24 syntax. This if for a FreeBSD Apache24 (2.4.29) server. The code is for "poudriere"

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;
    root /usr/local/share/poudriere/html;

    location /data {
        alias /usr/local/poudriere/data/logs/bulk;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /packages {
        root /usr/local/poudriere/data;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

I no nothing about Nginx and am getting nowhere in converting this configuration.

Thanks!